# How to design a circuit that creates high electric field between two conducting plates?

Tags: transformer, oscillator, crystal

I need to create an electric field of about ~1500V to move electrically charged particles in a container. I'm trying to convert a 9V DC battery to an AC signal using a crystal oscillator and then amplify the signal using a transformer to about  ~1500V. Here's the circuit I've designed but it looks to simple to work. Should the components be in series or parallel?

[image]

Comment: If your "crystal oscillator" is a two terminal device, it is just a crystal, and needs external components to form an oscillator.  A crystal oscillator module will have three or four terminals, and will be designed to operate on 5 volts or less - 9 volts will kill them.

Comment: "1500 V" is not an electric field strength; it's a voltage. A voltage over distance, that's a field strength.

Comment: Also, you will be multiplying the voltage using a transformer, at the cost of dividing the current by the same factor – the power at the output will have to completely come out of your poor oscillator. I don't really think you'll get far this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to do this you you.  We're all ganging up on you telling you bad things.  I'm going to tell you a bunch of them, and get it over with.

1. An oscillator doesn't work that way.
2. A 9V battery is a poor choice for a power source.  If you need 1mA at 1500 volts, then the primary side of the transformer will draw like 170mA from the battery.  It won't do that for very long.
3. An oscillator won't directly drive a transformer, even if you built a proper oscillator.  Most oscillators are intended to deliver a signal, not power.
4. An oscillator running at 10MHz will be awful fast for particles you are trying to move, and then see the motion.
5. "Series or parallel" is the least of your worries.

---

1. Figure out how much field strength you really need.  Figure out how much force it takes to move your particles, then calculate the force exerted by the capacitor plates on the particles.  [This ought to help you along the way.](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electricity_and_Magnetism/Book%3A_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(Tatum)/5%3A_Capacitors/5.12%3A__Force_Between_the_Plates_of_a_Plane_Parallel_Plate_Capacitor)  Maybe you already know this because it is part of a known physics experiment.  If so, then you should also find notes somewhere on how to calculate the expected power requirements - or even a note that says "we used plates sized X, powersupply Y volts and Z amperes."
2. Now that you have the voltage, figure out how much current you need.  It should be in some way proportional to the area of the plates and the area of the particles.
3. Now you have some idea of how much power you need.  The voltage times the current gives you the power.
4. Since you will start with a lower voltage and step it up, the current at the low voltage will go up by the same proportion that the voltage does.  Say you need 1mA at 1000V, and start from 10V.  You'll have to provide 100mA at 10V to get the required 1mA at 1000V.
5. Select a frequency, or range of frequencies.  Do you want your particles to vibrate in place, or would you prefer to see them drift towards on of the plates?  For vibration you need AC, preferably at a low frequency.  I don't know about you, but I can't see things that vibrate faster than a few Hertz, maybe a couple of tens of Hertz.
6. In either case, you need an oscillator operating at an appropriate frequency, and an amplifier that can provide your calculated power to the transformer.
7. If you want to see the particles vibrate, then you are done.
8. If you want to see the particles drift, then you need to convert the high voltage AC to DC.  That's done with a diode, followed by a capacitor to filter it nice and smooth.  You can also use a higher frequency for this.  It makes the transformer smaller, and makes it easier to filter the DC smooth.

That's a lot of stuff.

If you want, you can buy the powersupply you need instead of building one.  That's probably safer for you, given your lack of experience.  They might look expensive, but they are certain to be cheaper than a funeral.

In any case, I suggest you find someone who knows how to work safely around high voltage and work with that person and learn how to be safe yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. Where can I buy such device instead of making my own? I want the particles to drift to one of the plates and stay there until I reverse polarity.

Comment: @NovaliumCompany: [From somebody like this company.](https://www.phywe.com/en/phywe-power-supply-high-voltage-dc-0-25-kv-0-5-ma.html#tabs4)  Just search for high voltage DC power supplies for physics experiments.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there are some problems(quite a lot) with your circuit. But if you want to make 1500V I would suggest you make a simple voltage multipler using 600V plastic capacitors. It will run on mains AC. Just go through internet about the voltage multipler circuit. If you have 220VAC in your house then only 3 stages of the multipler will give you this much voltage. 
BEWARE: This is a dangerous experiment to do. It can kill you. 
 Don't do it if you do not have enough experience to work with AC

Answer (score 0):

Unless you mean the kind of 9V battery found in road works warning lamps, that battery won't last for long.

- I recommend using an EL wire power supply as the transformer stage. This will give you roughly 100V at 2kHz.
- Then use a [voltage multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier) with fast recovery diodes and low ESL caps, as the EL supply runs that thing at  2kHz.
- Use ten 1MΩ resistors in series (or a 10MΩ HV resistor) to limit the output current to a safe value.

---

If you happen to find an old HeNe laser power supply, you can simply use that one. It has a 1500V HVDC output.

---

- **Be careful, though. The 2kHz HVAC will not harm you because of the high frequency, but non-current-limited HVDC can certainly harm you!**